# Should we make the [multidex] tag a synonym of [android-multidex]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I recently noticed there are two tags [multidex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multidex) and [android-multidex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-multidex) that have the same description. Isn't this a bit of an unnecessary repetition as they both represent the exact same thing.

In my opinion, I think the [multidex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multidex) should be made a synonym of the [android-multidex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-multidex) tag rather than a parallel tag.

Comment: Agree with synonym [multidex] -> [android-multidex] as it's an Android-specific implementation.

Comment: Proposing and voting on tag synonyms is a privilege that requires 2500 reputation and I don't have up to that yet. So errr... Can anyone do that?

Comment: Moderators can do this. The tag synonym system for users is sub-par, so we typically handle it. However, since we’re not domain experts, we try to wait for a bit of community consensus agreeing it is a good idea to reduce the chances of mistakes. **What would really help here is if someone can look through the questions currently tagged [[tag:multidex]] and make sure that they *all* refer to Android Multidex.** If not, those need to be retagged first, while they’re still easy to find. Then I can create the synonym.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm an Android developer, so I can be a domain expert in this case. I went through 16 questions that were not tagged with [tag:android], and they all were related to Android. I've retagged them (except 1 with [tag:xamarin-android]). I can confirm this synonym request is valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Vadim Kotov mentions in a comment:

> I'm an Android developer, so I can be a domain expert in this case. I went through 16 questions that were not tagged with [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android), and they all were related to Android. I've retagged them (except 1 with [xamarin-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xamarin-android)). I can confirm this synonym request is valid.

This synonym request does seem to be valid. All the 411 questions were related to Android's multidex. I've gone ahead and synonymized the two tags in the following direction: [multidex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multidex) (× 411) → [android-multidex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-multidex) (× 394).